# How to implement Solr 7.3.1 Search with User Personalized based on history clicking user in oracle

Tags: oracle, solr

i need some advice and real solution in Solr 7.3.1 about how to searching music with user personalized based on history <del>and regional popularity</del> like youtube.

**Situation**

- Solr with music data (music data include different type of song/album/artist/playlist) include popularity field in each data.
- `popularity` is accumulate from all user history in oracle.
- Data user click / stream history in oracle database. (there are `user_id` for identity user)
- Data Geo location user stream history in oracle database. data will be limited to 36 regional location (using `regional_id`)
- Currently there is Implementation boosting recency with field registration date in music data using solr boost edismax (request using API with function recip)
- Currently Implementation global popularity with field popularity in music data using solr boost edismax (request using API with function log)

**Question**

- How to implement searching with user personalized, which data is in oracle database model like log / history stream ?
- <del>How to implement searching with regional popularity? should implement new 36 field (`pop_reg_1, pop_reg_2, pop_reg_n...` ) ?</del>

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to answer some of these questions - the first, for example, is very broad. For the second you don't need 36 new fields in Solr; a single `multiValued` field should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFaber Can solr boosting using multiValued with specific index like pop[0] or pop[n]? I also confuse to write it all into simple question, also i remove last question maybe it's not relevant.